# "BindException: Address already in use" after restart of app

Tags: java, android, sockets

I got a BindException when i restart my application. It acts as a server waiting for remote control messages. The ServerSocket is running in a background thread (AsyncTask). After restart of my application i always get the exception mentioned above. I have to wait for like 10 minutes until it can bind again to the port in order to listen.

I tried different ports (all >50000) so I'm sure there is no other application blocking my port. I tried to be careful about closing the socket and i tried to use the SO_REUSEADDR option. Also I am sure that there is only one connection open at run time, since i logged every socketbind.

So what i think is, that the connection is not closed properly. I've read about the habit of sockets not closing instantly. But i cannot wait like 10 minutes on every restart of the application and i did not find a way to shorten or kill this time.

Do you have any ideas?

The exception:

```
10-04 16:39:22.526: WARN/System.err(4974): java.net.BindException: Address already in use
10-04 16:39:22.526: WARN/System.err(4974):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.bind(Native Method)
10-04 16:39:22.526: WARN/System.err(4974):     at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.bind(BlockGuard.java:275)
10-04 16:39:22.526: WARN/System.err(4974):     at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(PlainSocketImpl.java:165)
10-04 16:39:22.526: WARN/System.err(4974):     at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:123)
10-04 16:39:22.526: WARN/System.err(4974):     at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:74)
10-04 16:39:22.526: WARN/System.err(4974):     at com.*******.remote.RemoteHandlerListener$1.doInBackground(RemoteHandlerListener.java:114)
```

The code:

```
ServerSocket server;
try {
    server = new ServerSocket();
    server.setReuseAddress(true);
    server.bind(new InetSocketAddress(serverport));
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return null;
}

while (true) {
    BufferedReader inStream = null;
    Socket client = null;
    try {
        client = server.accept();
        inStream = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( client.getInputStream()));
        // read from stream
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (inStream != null) {
            try {
                inStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
        if (client != null) {
            try {
                client.close();
            } catch (IOException e) { }
        }
    }
}
try {
    server.close();
} catch (IOException e) { }
```

The exception is thrown on the server.bind-statement.

EDIT: 
Cause of the problem: The thread will not terminate itself since the accept-call is blocking. The program did not terminate completely and the socket was not unbound.

Solution: Set SO_TIMEOUT to the socket and check for isCancelled in the while()-loop. This way the thread will finish if you call cancel() on it.

Comment: Can you define "restart" and "background thread"?  Are you killing the app from the task manager and starting it again, or just reinstalling the .apk?  When you say background thread, are you using an AsyncTask, or a traditional Java thread, and it is marked as a daemon?  These are all relevant to how the application lifecycle and the VM work with the concurrency units.

Comment: By restarting i mean pressing the back button in the starting activity and then starting it again by clicking on the icon thus invoking the onDestroy-method where i stop the thread. No taskmanager or reinstallation involved. Killing the application via taskmanager solves the problem but is no real solution.

Comment: As background thread i use a AsyncTask.

Comment: Hitting back then restarting doesn't call onDestroy.  onDestroy is only called if the OS completely kills the app (which is what is happening when you use the task manager).  You need to move your cleanup to onPause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to print the stacktrace of all the caught exceptions. That will probably help a lot. Maybe there is something wrong in your code you posted. You are creating try-catch blocks without handeling the Exception. You even don't know if there are any.

---

Update: Next step is to make sure your application is really stopped. At first sight of your code you **never** quit your infinite loop of accepting clients. Try to fix that and add a print statement after you close the serversocket:

```
try {
    server.close();
    System.out.println("Server successfully stopped.");
} catch (IOException e) { }
```

Make sure you find this in the output of your application.

And if you want to be sloppy, you can enforce the application (and the serversocket) to shutdown using:

```
System.exit(0);
```

Comment: I added the missing printStackTrace()s. No other exceptions are thrown besides the BindException.

Comment: Yeah that was the problem. I did not interrupt the Thread but checked if the thread should stop (via isCancelled) and let the thread kill itself. Now what happens if there is no incoming connection? Yes, the thread will not terminate itself since the accept()-call is blocking. This way the thread did not stop. Stupid mistake ;)

Answer (score 0):

I Agree - Usually this indicates that the restart failed to terminate the server process properly. Somehow it's still running and therefore the port is still blocked.

Waiting for 10 minutes is somewhat long. Just check (if possible) if the previously running java process has terminated.

Comment: That was a useful hint. Making sure the application is really stopped by killing it manually helped. But how can i make sure my application is always terminated or how can i terminate it on restart?

Comment: Identify the operating system process that was created when you "started" the application, and then you know which one you need to watch to see if it still exists.  Depending on packaging of the launcher, it will either be the name of the executable launched or java.  Killing that process from the task manager / process list will close the socket, but some care should be taken if the process is one that might leave inconsistent state on the disk.  Some less robust applications don't relaunch cleanly when they've been killed in critical sections.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already, you should study the Android dev stuff on [Activity Lifecycles](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).  The tl;dr of that article is that the Android operating system makes absolutely no guarantee about when an application will be killed except that it can happen any time, and that's why they provide the onPause, onResume, onRestart, etc.  You can't ever guarantee that your app will always die completely, but you can perform your own cleanup, and I'd recommend killing your thread and closing your socket (or some other management) inside of onPause.

In addition, when using Java sockets (whether it's Android or not), it's never good practice to let program termination be the action that closes your sockets.  You should almost always close them yourself in some sort of clean-up area.  Especially when dealing with threads.

Update:  You said that you are hitting back and then restarting.  This doesn't call onDestroy.  onDestroy is only called if the OS needs the memory and kills your app completely (the equivalent of killing it in the Task Manager)

Comment: You are right. onStop() would've been the way to go then i think.